# Jasmine - Inject service into component thats provided by another component

Tags: angular, service, jasmine, karma-runner, code-injection

I am testing my Angular5-App with Jasmine and Karma and have a problem I cant solve.

I wrote a mapping-builder, that uses OpenLayers, to create a map. 
Here is an example how it works:

```
<map-builder [width]="800">
  <layer [name]="TestLayer">
     <marker [lat]="lat" [lng]="lng"><marker>
  </layer>
<map-builder>
```

The MapBuilderComponent provides the MappingService. All Childcomponents, like layer and marker are using the same instance of this service. The MapBuilder calls an initMap(options) function on the service to create a new ol.Map().
LayerComp and MarkerComp are using the same service to add a layer or feature to the map.

I now want to create a MapBuilderComponent (with Inputs) in the test, test if its defined (for now thats enough) and then, in a second test, create a LayerComponent (with Inputs) and test if the layer is defined. So I want to use only one Instance of the mappingService for all tests. After the MapBuilderComponent is created, the mappingService should have a defined map (of Type ol.Map). The second tests need this map to add a layer. How do I inject the service (with the defined map) into my LayerComponent?

Or is there a better way to test this?

All the best,
Thalion

Answer (score 1):

Every service is a single instance of its class in Angular. They're singletons, and that's why you use dependency injection.

To get a service in one of your tests, you can use either the testbed, or inject the service into your test.

Let's see with the test bed :

```
const service: MappingService = TestBed.get(MappingService);
```

This will give you the instance of your service.

Since you're testing components, and not this service, you should also provide a mock of this service to your test bed. Here is how :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [/* modules */],
  declarations: [YourComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: MappingService, useValue: myServiceMock }
  ]
})
  .compileComponents();
```

Where

```
myServiceMock = {
  initMap: () => null, // return what you want here, preferably typed as the type returned by your function
};
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick reply. I tried that 100 times. This is my code https://pastebin.com/cKGXUFYs
Instead of declarations I also used imports: [MappingBuilderModule] because this module exports all the other components. It crashes as soon as it reaches layerFixture.detectChanges(); because it tries to call addLayer(layer) on the mappingServiceMock. With this Error "Failed to load ng:///DynamicTestModule/LayerComponent_Host.ngfactory.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Comment: Well, that's because you didn't mock your service ! it is making an HTTP call, you should mock that call and return a dummy value to work on. Assume that all unit tests must be offline, this is easier. So you need to mock `addLayer` to **not make an HTTP call**, and **return a dummy value to use**.

Comment: addLayer is a predefined function by OpenLayers. Im not making any HTTP calls. And this pushes the layer to the map. Has nothing to do with my service. The addLayer(layer)-method from my Service just calls map.addLayer(layer). Thats all.

Comment: I may have got you wrong, but the point still doesn't change : you **need to mock `addLayer`**. To mock it, you can simply use a spy, such as `spyOn(OpenLayers, 'addLayer').and.returnValue(null)`. This will mock your function and allow you to get rid of the error.

Comment: But honestly, the best way for me to help you is to have your code, and I don't mean the HTML one ...

Comment: Okay, that works so far. Thank you. But now, the layer will never be added to the map. Shouldn't I somehow test if the layer has been added to the map?

Comment: Well, the same way you did this, you should test if your component called the methods responsible for adding a layer to the map. In my case, I was using leaflet, and 2 methods were called : `addLayer`, and `addTo`. I spied on both, and checked if they were called with the correct arguments. Because your job isn't to test if the framework is working well, but to test if your component is working well. This is a subtle notion I had a hard time understanding myslef